# System fonts are unreadable, haywire

Tags: fonts

This is exactly the same issue as [elementary OS system fonts haywire](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/13499/elementary-os-system-fonts-haywire) but it is unsolved there.

Here is my screenshot:
[image: enter image descriptionhttps://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/13499/elementary-os-system-fonts-haywire here]

1. I am inclined to believe this is related to screenshot tool on elementary. I was taking some screenshots in an evince window. It glitched to this font for a split second every time I tried to do an area grab screenshot. Then, it occured permanently. I can read all the fonts inside the browser application window (not the address bar or tabs though), so I kept on working thinking I'll just do a reboot later, but it persists.
2. The problem does not occur in Guest Session, or a new account as I just created.

Comment: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11687/fonts-looks-weird-at-loki-and-just-in-my-user-session-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score -1):

Following the instructions on [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11687/fonts-looks-weird-at-loki-and-just-in-my-user-session-how-do-i-fix-it) and reseting all font-related stuff works for me.