# Font problems in elementary os

Tags: pantheon, fonts

I've got a trouble with wrong font displaying in elementary OS. The text of all system headings, controls and terminal is blurred and looks like a long curve line.

[image: My desktop screenshot]
[image: My terminal screenshot]
But text inside applications looks fine as it was. So I decided that problem could be connected with pantheon.

I googled it, but found only problems with resizing, not blurring. Now I am stuck at fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that worked for me is 
[Fonts looks weird at Loki (and just in my user session!). How do I fix it?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11687/fonts-looks-weird-at-loki-and-just-in-my-user-session-how-do-i-fix-it)

But I got an error:

`GLib-GIO-Message: 21:06:40.395: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.
 Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.`

I solved it as described here https://blog.csdn.net/juwenkailaodi/article/details/86525841]

`export GIO_EXTRA_MODULES=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17783/17985), the scrambled text in window titles might be due to a Screenshot utility 'conceal text' bug. 
Suggested fix:

- launch Screenshot
- in Screenshot preferences window, turn off 'Conceal Text' option:

[image]

- If this helps, please report this bug to elementary OS devs @ https://github.com/elementary

Comment: Could you please help me with opening this preferences, because the only thing I could see is https://imgur.com/kpHJrWS

Comment: Probably that doesn't help, because I turned off all settings and rebooted, but problem still exists

Comment: The thing that worked for me is 
[https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11687/fonts-looks-weird-at-loki-and-just-in-my-user-session-how-do-i-fix-it]

But I got
`GLib-GIO-Message: 21:06:40.395: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend. Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.`
Then I fixed it as mentioned here
 [https://blog.csdn.net/juwenkailaodi/article/details/86525841]

`export GIO_EXTRA_MODULES=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/`

Comment: So, to be clear, did you finally fix this font issue with the terminal commands or not?

Comment: Yes @a-tokarev, I fixed it by using commands in previous comment

Comment: Can you post the solution like an answer and accept it later in order to be found easily for anyone who has a similar issue later?  Also all other elementary OS  readers here to understand that you do not need help with this anymore.